# PHP - How to convert the YouTube URL with Regex

Tags: php, regex, url, youtube

How can convert the below youtube urls

```
$url1 = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=136pEZcb1Y0&feature=fvhl
$url2 = http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvhl&v=136pEZcb1Y0
```

into

```
 $url_embedded = http://www.youtube.com/v/136pEZcb1Y0
```

using Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example solution:

PHP:

```
preg_replace('/.+(\?|&)v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*/', 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=$2', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=136pEZcb1Y0&feature=fvhl');
```

Match:

```
^.+(\?|&)v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*$
```

Replace with:

```
http://youtube.com/watch?v=$2
```

Here's how it works: [regex analyzer](http://bit.ly/d2YdL6).

Comment: could you please update it for both default, and SHORT youtube url

Answer (score 2):

suicideducky's answer is fine, but you changed the requirements. Try

```
preg_match($url1, "/v=(\w+)/", $matches);
$url_embedded = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $matches[1];
```

In case the wrong version was still cached, I meant `$matches[1]`!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but will that not just find the second match of "v=(\w+)" and ad it to youtube.com/v/ ?

Comment: The first match, as `$matches[0]` contains the whole matched text. `$matches[1]` contains the video ID because that's what's captured in the parentheses.

Comment: +1 Entirely forgot about groupings behavior.
I also edited and posted before I realised another had replies, so sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

add the string "http://www.youtube.com/watch/"
to the result of applying the regex "v=(\w+)" to the url(s) should do the job.

\w specifies alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _) and will thus stop at the &

EDIT for updated question.
My approach seems a little hackish.

so get the result of applying the regex "v=(\w+)" and then apply the regex "(\w+)" to it.
Then prefix it with the string "http://www.youtube.com/v/".

so to sum up:

```
"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + ( result of "(\w+)" applies to the result of ( "v=(\w+)" applied to the origional url ) )
```

EDITED AGAIN this approach assumes you are using a regex function that matches a substring instead of the whole string

Also, MvanGeest's version is superior to mine.

Comment: Please see the updated question, need output like http://www.youtube.com/v/136pEZcb1Y0

Comment: Just extract the parenthesized group and add it to the string "http://www.youtube.com/v/"

Comment: Isn't that what's in my answer?